# How to implement NfcvService in ionic 2 project ? Now I am getting some error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I implement NFC module my ionic project with use `import { NfcvService } from 'cordova-nfcv-plugin/ionic2';` .

I am getting this error on conlose,
[console error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCITp.png)

Comment: show your component file where you used?.

Answer (score 0):

Just for an suggestion Make sure you have imported NFC in app module and current component,

Here is an Example

```
import {NfcvService} from 'cordova-nfc-plugin/ionic2';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    NfcvService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { NfcvService } from 'cordova-nfc-plugin/ionic2';

  constructor(public nfcvService: NfcvService) {
      nfcvService.addNdefListener();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nfcvService.onTag().subscribe((tag) => {
      //Avoid reading null tag on first call
      if (tag) {
        console.log('Found tag:', tag);
        this.tag = tag; // here you can use variable further 
      }
    });
  }
```

I hope its solve your problem.

For more reference visit site here

https://github.com/valentiniljaz/cordova-nfc-plugin/blob/master/ionic2/readme.md

Comment: Thank you for answer , but ı applied these steps according to document .